# NestedScrollView breaks suggestions in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Here is the strange behavior. I have this layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/AppTheme.FragmentBackground.XXXX.Parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        layout="@layout/layout_appbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

So far, everything seems perfect. Although, if I replace the LinearLayout with a NestedScrollView, all of a sudden, the suggestions just do not work! If I remove the nested scrollview, everything seems to work again. Here are my gradle dependencies:

> ```
> implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
> implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.0'
> implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0'
> implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
>
> implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
> implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
> implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
> implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.5'
> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
> implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
> implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
> implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
> implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.5' //  Forecast Charts
> implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0' //  maps v2
> implementation 'androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0'
> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
> implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.4.0'
> // needed for timestamps manip
> implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.11.2'
>
> implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.2.1"
> implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.2.1"
> implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.2.1"
>
> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-barcode-scanning:18.1.0'
> //implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.0.2'
>
> implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
> ```

while my gradle is gradle-7.5-bin.zip and my plugins are

```
plugins {
     id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
     id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
     id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
version '2.0.1' apply false }
```

[image]

[image]

Also a popup of broken IDE is appeared and here is the log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jetbrains.android.dom.AttributeProcessingUtil.registerAttributesForClassAndSuperclasses(AttributeProcessingUtil.java:315)
at org.jetbrains.android.dom.AttributeProcessingUtil.processLayoutAttributes(AttributeProcessingUtil.java:604)
at org.jetbrains.android.dom.AttributeProcessingUtil.processAttributes(AttributeProcessingUtil.java:681)
at org.jetbrains.android.dom.AndroidDomExtender.registerExtensions(AndroidDomExtender.java:56)
at org.jetbrains.android.dom.AndroidDomExtender.registerExtensions(AndroidDomExtender.java:28)
at com.intellij.util.xml.reflect.DomExtenderEP.extend(DomExtenderEP.java:91)
at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DynamicGenericInfo.runDomExtenders(DynamicGenericInfo.java:124)
at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DynamicGenericInfo.lambda$checkInitialized$0(DynamicGenericInfo.java:55)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$1.computePreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:114)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionGuard.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionGuard.java:44)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:68)
at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DynamicGenericInfo.checkInitialized(DynamicGenericInfo.java:54)
at com.intellij.util.xml.impl.DynamicGenericInfo.getAttributeChildrenDescriptions(DynamicGenericInfo.java:231)
at com.intellij.xml.impl.dom.AbstractDomChildrenDescriptor.getAttributeDescriptor(AbstractDomChildrenDescriptor.java:184)
at com.intellij.xml.impl.dom.AbstractDomChildrenDescriptor.getAttributeDescriptor(AbstractDomChildrenDescriptor.java:195)
at org.jetbrains.android.dom.layout.LayoutElementDescriptor.getAttributeDescriptor(LayoutElementDescriptors.kt:124)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlAttributeDelegate.getDescriptionImpl(XmlAttributeDelegate.java:68)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlAttributeDelegate.lambda$getDescriptor$0(XmlAttributeDelegate.java:55)
at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager$1.compute(CachedValuesManager.java:158)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.doCompute(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:39)
at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.lambda$getValueWithLock$3(CachedValueBase.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.computeData(CachedValueBase.java:42)
at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.lambda$getValueWithLock$4(CachedValueBase.java:227)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager$1.computePreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:114)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionGuard.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionGuard.java:44)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.RecursionManager.doPreventingRecursion(RecursionManager.java:68)
at com.intellij.util.CachedValueBase.getValueWithLock(CachedValueBase.java:228)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiCachedValueImpl.getValue(PsiCachedValueImpl.java:28)
at com.intellij.util.CachedValuesManagerImpl.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManagerImpl.java:72)
at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:155)
at com.intellij.psi.util.CachedValuesManager.getCachedValue(CachedValuesManager.java:121)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlAttributeDelegate.getDescriptor(XmlAttributeDelegate.java:53)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlAttributeImpl.getDescriptor(XmlAttributeImpl.java:191)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlAttributeReference$1.compute(XmlAttributeReference.java:23)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlAttributeReference$1.compute(XmlAttributeReference.java:20)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.NullableLazyValue.getValue(NullableLazyValue.java:20)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlAttributeReference.getDescriptor(XmlAttributeReference.java:110)
at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlAttributeReference.resolve(XmlAttributeReference.java:50)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.TargetElementUtilBase.getReferencedElement(TargetElementUtilBase.java:177)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.TargetElementUtilBase.doGetReferenceOrReferencedElement(TargetElementUtilBase.java:165)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.TargetElementUtilBase.getReferenceOrReferencedElement(TargetElementUtilBase.java:210)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.TargetElementUtilBase.getReferencedElement(TargetElementUtilBase.java:254)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.TargetElementUtilBase.doFindTargetElement(TargetElementUtilBase.java:233)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.TargetElementUtilBase.findTargetElement(TargetElementUtilBase.java:298)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.TargetElementUtil.findTargetElement(TargetElementUtil.java:147)
at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.psi.impl.OCTargetElementUtil.findTargetElement(OCTargetElementUtil.java:47)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.text.TextEditorPsiDataProvider.getPsiElementIn(TextEditorPsiDataProvider.java:226)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.text.TextEditorPsiDataProvider.getSlowData(TextEditorPsiDataProvider.java:139)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.text.TextEditorPsiDataProvider.lambda$getData$0(TextEditorPsiDataProvider.java:93)
at com.intellij.ide.impl.DataManagerImpl.getSlowData(DataManagerImpl.java:153)
at com.intellij.ide.impl.DataManagerImpl.lambda$getDataRule$2(DataManagerImpl.java:121)
at com.intellij.ide.impl.DataManagerImpl.lambda$getDataRule$4(DataManagerImpl.java:126)
at com.intellij.ide.impl.DataManagerImpl.getDataFromProvider(DataManagerImpl.java:77)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.PreCachedDataContext.getData(PreCachedDataContext.java:182)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.PreCachedDataContext$InjectedDataContext.getData(PreCachedDataContext.java:327)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.DataKey.getData(DataKey.java:63)
at org.jetbrains.android.quickDefinitions.AndroidImplementationViewSessionFactory.createSession(AndroidImplementationViewSession.kt:55)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.hint.actions.ShowRelatedElementsActionBase.performForContext(ShowRelatedElementsActionBase.java:86)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.hint.actions.ShowRelatedElementsActionBase.actionPerformed(ShowRelatedElementsActionBase.java:63)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.ActionProcessor.performAction(ActionProcessor.java:65)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher$1.performAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:579)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.lambda$doPerformActionInner$10(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:704)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:95)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.lambda$doPerformActionInner$11(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:704)
at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:256)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.doPerformActionInner(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:701)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:645)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processAction(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:590)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.processActionOrWaitSecondStroke(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:473)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.inInitState(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:462)
at com.intellij.openapi.keymap.impl.IdeKeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(IdeKeyEventDispatcher.java:227)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchKeyEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:804)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:740)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:439)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:803)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:438)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:119)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:604)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:436)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:873)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:484)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
```

Comment: That is a long stack dump: 89 calls deep. Is that normal?

Comment: What version of Android Studio?

Comment: Is there some implicit infinite recursion in your data?

Comment: i honestly do not know why this stack dump is long...
I tested it on both latest stable and canary builds

recursion in my XML? do u see something like this? i dont think so i do :/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/AppTheme.FragmentBackground.XXXX.Parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        layout="@layout/layout_appbar" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what exactly is this ?

Comment: @Dimitris Katikaridis: It is a code dump. We have no idea why they are doing this. Perhaps they have a commission to generate a certain number of reputation points through [Fiverr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiverr) and are sprinkling more or less random code over mostly year-old questions (though not in this particular case) in the hope of a random upvote. That time could be spend so much better, e.g., by escaping illiteracy and improving their English.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Ctrl + Space to trigger suggestions within a NestedScrollView, as this shortcut should work both inside and outside of it. Also, make sure you're using the latest Android Studio version and attempt to resolve the issue by cleaning, rebuilding, and syncing your project, as these steps often help address problems within Android Studio.

Comment: i tried it many times and it didnt work. i think its something deeper

Comment: Check From Where the NullPointerExecption is Coming